# Program with pointers not working

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning to work with the pointers, I did a simple exercise but unfortunately it does not work I would be happy if you help me to fix it.

The Exercise - just got a value and send it to function thet Raises him one.

The code-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incNum(int* p)
{
*p++;
}


int main()
{
int number = 20;
int* p;

p = &number;

printf("%d\n",number);
incNum(&p);
printf("%d\n",number);
return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for the help I appreciate it very much

Comment: OT: It shall at least be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say:

```
number  20   | 1024
       value | Address
```

Having `int* p = &number`:

```
p      1024  | 1000
       value | Address
```

Therefore:

```
incNum(&p) ==> incNum(1000)
*p ==> 1024
(*p)++ ==>  1025
```

It is not the value you wanted to be passed, therefore it should be `incNum(p) ==> incNum(1024)`

In the end, this is how it should look like:

```
void incNum(int* p)
{
  (*p)++;
}

int main(void)
{
  int number = 20;
  int* p;    
  p = &number;    
  printf("%d\n",number);
  incNum(p);
  printf("%d\n",number);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3332897 check the updated answer, are you doing anything different ?

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add +

Answer (score 3):

Your function call is wrong. It should be like

```
incNum(p);
```

In your function change `*p++` to `(*p)++` to increment the value of `number` by `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the precedence table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

`*p++` translates to `*(p++)` which changes the pointer and returns the content of where it was pointing before the change (which you are throwing away). What you want is the opposite, i.e. `(*p)++`.

This is besides the fact that you should have called the function like:

```
incNum(p);
```

---

As a side note, try to compile with warnings enabled (always do this). If you are using gcc, this is with the `-Wall` flag, so for example:

```
gcc -Wall your_file.c
```

Also, make sure you don't ignore those warnings ;)

Comment: Even though the accepted answer contains the same information (and therefore it _is_ working), I'm telling you this for future reference. You don't call a doctor and ask "I feel bad" and expect a prescription. You also can't say "Still not working" and expect anyone to help you. In such a situation, since every answer basically has said the same thing, you need to edit your answer and the new code that you have (with the changes applied) and explain what happens and why you think it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you passed the wrong argument in your `incNum` function, you should either pass `incNum(p);` or `incNum(&number);`.

`incNum(&p);` means you passed the address of the pointer `p` which points to number and you incremented its value.

Also `*p++;` should be `(*p)++;`